# Spark job returns "Paused for longer than xxx seconds and unable to write pages to client"

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am working on a spark job that is responsible for reading data from a cassandra db and then performing some operations on the data, like updating some records, etc based on conditions. The spark works for some keyspaces and tabkes but for some other keyspaces it failes too early with a similar stacktrace like

```
   WARN  2022-03-30 21:39:50,082 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, 10.0.144.110, executor 0): com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Paused for longer than 600 seconds and unable to write pages to client
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException.copy(DriverException.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:26)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultContinuousPagingResult$RowIterator.maybeFetchNextResult(DefaultContinuousPagingResult.java:72)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultContinuousPagingResult$RowIterator.computeNext(DefaultContinuousPagingResult.java:62)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultContinuousPagingResult$RowIterator.computeNext(DefaultContinuousPagingResult.java:50)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:30)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115)
    at com.company.spark.job.MySparkJobClass.lambda$handleMovingRackspaceImagesToS3$e3b46054$1(MySparkJobClass.java:167)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2073)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2073)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:344)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Paused for longer than 600 seconds and unable to write pages to client
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException.copy(DriverException.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:184)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ContinuousPagingQueue.onResponse(ContinuousPagingQueue.java:148)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.MultiResponseRequestHandler.setResult(MultiResponseRequestHandler.java:888)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.MultiResponseRequestHandler.onSet(MultiResponseRequestHandler.java:600)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1253)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1160)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1407)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1177)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1221)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:647)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:582)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:499)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:461)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ClientWriteException: Paused for longer than 600 seconds and unable to write pages to client
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:124)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:58)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:303)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:274)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
    ... 29 more
```

I found out from [here](https://books.japila.pl/apache-spark-internals/configuration-properties/#sparkexecutorheartbeatmaxfailures) that spark executors have 60 default maximum failures with 10s for the heartbeat, resulting to the 600s but a question the question is now, what causes these executures to fail ? Any hint that could help?

*Update:*

> Number of times an Executor tries sending heartbeats to the driver before it gives up and exits (with exit code 56).
> Default: 60
> For example, with max failures 60 (the default) and spark.executor.heartbeatInterval 10s, then Executor will try to send heartbeats for up to 600s (10 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

The `ClientWriteException` gets thrown by the Java driver when the server-side read took too long. Without knowing the table schema and what query your Spark job was running, it's hard to know why reads are taking a long time.

Admittedly, the stack trace looks alien to me. You didn't specify the version of Spark connector and Java driver so I'm assuming that you're possibly using a very old version of the Java driver which is no longer supported.

If you update your original question with background details such as versions, schema, CQL query, minimal code to replicate, I'd be happy to review it and update my answer. Cheers!